# eloquent many to many shows double results

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models User and Afdeling('department'). Between them is a many-to-many relationship.

In my junction table i have two entries:

```
Afdeling_id | user_id
----------------------
3           |   45                 
4           |   45
```

Now i want to display both departmens that are connected with id 45.

Now in my controller i do:

```
$afdelingslijst = User::find(45)->afdelingen;
```

In my view i have

```
<?php
      foreach($afdelingslijst as $item) {
     echo $item->pluck('afdelingen');
}
    ?>
```

As output i see "department1 department1". This should be "department1 department2".

Why could this be happening?

Comment: How about your model code and your actual table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using "pluck". You should access it as if you're accessing an object's attribute, like so:

```
echo $item->afdelingen;
```

The definition of [pluck](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Builder.html#_pluck) is to "Pluck a single column from the database".